# AngularJS Application not booting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to start an angularjs project, however for some reason I can't seem to get it started correctly. It probably is some kind of mistake that I am to blind for to see. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WebUX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="webux">
    <section class="sidebar">
        <nav class="page-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#/home" class="home"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#/about" class="about"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#/contact" class="contact"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>

    <section class="content">
        <div class="slide" ng-view></div>
    </section>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('webux', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    console.log($scope);
});
```

Also the console log in the HomeCtrl does not get fired.

**Update**

Just to add some info:

- Console is empty
- All script files are correctly referenced

Comment: Yes, I see, deleted the comment but you are fast =)

Comment: Is it angular 1.3 ? If the anser is Yes. Try with Html5 mode off. If it works then enable it again and add <base> tag to your page.

Comment: what does the console says ?

Comment: yes, it is 1.3, did I miss something in the new version? Also the console says nothing

Comment: The base tag and html5 mode off doesn't change anything

Comment: should add `$routeProvider.otherwise` see docs

Comment: are all of your script paths correct?

Comment: that also does not work, @charliefl

Comment: @BrianMcCall, yes I don't get any 404's in the console

Comment: Then may be "Let the mighty Ctrl+F5 help you!" ...sometimes it really helps =)

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in plunkr for example?

Comment: angular.module('webux')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    
    console.log("hello world")
  });

Comment: Btw, does browser request js files and html templates? What does Network tab say?

Comment: put some js breakpoints early in chrome and see what happens. Better than console.log. If they're not getting hit at all you have a bigger problem.

Comment: they are loaded with 200-OK, so that isn't the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thank you all a lot for helping me out, however I found the solution. As you can see in my code example, I use `<div class="slide" ng-view></div>` to specify where the views should be rendered. After I inspected the element for a few times, I found that chrome stripped that empty property.

`<div class="slide" data-ng-view` does work (notice the 'data-').

Comment: Wow! Good lesson...Thank you. Then it's better to use <ng-view> as an element.

Comment: better go edit all those answers in SO claiming 'data-' is functionally trivial

Comment: or use this ng-view=""